# Do we have any promotional material?

Tags: discussion

I'm wanting to print out some sort of flyer/promotional stuff for this site to post around town, but i'm not that great at designing stuff.  Do we have any pre-made promotional flyers for the site, or if not can we get some/have some made?

Comment: **Related:** [Can we get a graphic design?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/477/can-we-get-a-graphic-design)

Comment: We don't have anything I know of, but would support the creation of some (and ogger to put the files up on my blog to host them, since SE doesn't have file storage).

Answer (score 1):

As the site does not currently have a design, we do not have any promotional material that is explicitly for the RPG site. Once a design is developed (so, post-site-graduation), then work on promotional material can begin.

Otherwise, Beta sites usually instead use our general Stack Exchange materials instead, the most prominent of which are our stickers and T-Shirts.